# Obtain token text after parsing XML with DomParser

Tags: node.js, parsing, dom

I am having some issues with [DomParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser) in NodeJS.  So I get a response from a Microsoft API, and I parse it

```
const dom = new DomParser().parseFromString(rawData, "text/xml");
console.log(dom);
```

The output of the above looks something like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"
    xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        //some header stuff
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body
        xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wst:TokenType>urn:passport:compact</wst:TokenType>
            <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken Id="Compact0"
                    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">Some Token
                </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have remove some irrelevant tags but what I want to obtain is the token within `BinarySecurityToken`, which above is the test Some Token.  So with the dom above, I do

```
const node = dom.getElementsByTagName("wsse:BinarySecurityToken");
console.log(node);
```

But that seems to output the following

```
[
  Node {
    namespace: 'BinarySecurityToken',
    text: undefined,
    _selfCloseTag: false
  }
]
```

So how can I obtain the token using this DomParser?

Thanks

Comment: use an xml parser: https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/HEAD/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md, since this one doesn't implement [getElementsByTagNameNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS)

Answer (score 1):

First, `getElementsByTagName` returns a a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name; you only need the first - so add `[0]`.
Second - the token is a text element which is a child of that first element; you need to account for that, too.

So all together:

```
node = dom.getElementsByTagName("wsse:BinarySecurityToken")[0];
console.log(node.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Output:

```
Some Token
```